# Ошибка запуска tensorflow, не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tensorflow

Использую python 3.8. При попытке работать с библиотекой, выдает ошибку. Подскажите как решить

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)

  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Не найден указанный модуль.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\gumin\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\gumin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Не найден указанный модуль.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте скачать MSVCP140.dll и вставить его в папку system32, если не сможете или если это не сработает, попробуйте скачать [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 64bit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Так же не забывайте, что tensorFlow работает только с 64 битной версией python. Насколько я помню, при попытке установить TensorFlow в 32 битным python вы просто не найдете нужный пакет, но всё-таки проверьте на всякий случай, вдруг у вас каким то чудом python 32bit

Comment: Ура, заработало! Никак не мог тоже TF у себя на ноутбуке победить, а всё было так просто, оказывается.